# How can I import/export a MySQL database without redirection?

Tags: mysql

I've been told that redirection via shell (e.g. `<` and `>` ) can (not always) affect the collation of a database (.e.g utf8). How can I import an export without redirecting so that I don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Never heard of that before. Do you have some examples/proof for this? I don't think that redirection does something like that since *nix is completely aware of UTF8 and handles it as it should.

Comment: @DrColossos, perhaps not correctly setting the code page in a Windows command-prompt could cause scrambling.

Comment: I keep meaning to go back and ask someone who understands the reason of what causes this... because I don't deal with it often enough.

Answer (score 4):

There's always the [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html) utility, however, your source would have to be delimited values... such as those obtained from a "SELECT * FROM ... INTO OUTFILE ..."

If you're moving large amounts of data, it might be faster to use this *bulk loading* method anyway.

Beware of the consequences it may have with replication however.

Comment: What about an export program? I agree that there should also be a way for an executable to directly read and write a source file, but then again, these come from *nix, where redirection and piping are much more frequently used than in Windows.

Comment: If you're looking for a GUI/Windows interface to work with, try TOAD for mysql. http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/

Comment: Command line tool are capable of directly reading/writeing files too.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do this command on the import server

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

This will show you the default collation of the database you want to import into.

You can also [change the import database's collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-database.html) if needed.

UPDATE !!!

First of all, I would look at the what the OS says the character set is. On the Linux command line just run this:

```
echo ${LANG}
```

From the MySQL point of view

You could explicitly name the default character set in the mysqldump

```
--default-character-set (default is utf8)
```

You can see it in the mysql client:

```
mysql> show variables like '%charac%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

As for collation, you may need to set one or more environment variables like these:

```
mysql> show variables like '%coll%';<BR>
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Set these explicitly upon export for mysqldump and import for mysql as follows:

```
mysqldump -h... -u... -p... --default-character-set=utf8 --triggers --routines source_db | mysql -h... -u... -p... --collation_connection=latin1_swedish_ci -A -Dtarget_db
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question completely. I think the question is about the wrong conversion **while** directing the output of the backup to a `.sql` file and not the change of the collation. So the problem seems to be in the export itself, not in the collation of the table.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: +1 I think the default-charset option is the important part and good explanation!

Comment: @DrColossos +1 in Thanks for Looking over my Shoulder and Making Sure I answered the question contextually !!!

Comment: ;) Nevermind, I also learned something new!

Comment: It is worth noting that `utf8` in mysql is not exactly `utf8`. What is more likely needed is actually `--default-character-set=utf8mb4`. (Tested and verified that is does make a difference)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could log into MySQL and do:

```
mysql> source myfile.sql
```

That takes the shell out of the picture altogether - but I would still recommend double-checking environment variables like `NLS_LANG`.

Comment: or mysql -e "source myfile.sql"